# find number of lines with length more than 5

Tags: c, string, fgets

Let's assume I've got a file

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
abcdefg
abcdefgh
abcdefgh
abcdefg
abcdef
abcde
abcd
abc
ab
a
```

I need to find lines with `length >= 5`.
Here is the code

```
int cOriginal(char *fileName)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char line[256];
    int numberOfStrings = 0;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        if (strlen(line) >= sizeCap)
        {
            numberOfStrings++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return numberOfStrings;
}
```

where `sizeCap` is a constant, defined as

```
const int sizeCap = 5;
```

My `main()` function

```
int main()
{
    char filename[] = "file.txt";
    int cnt3 = cOriginal(filename); // th
    printf("Using function3: %d", cnt3);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it returns `10` instead of `8`. And I don't get the idea why.

I don't have an IDE beside me so I have to use g++ and command line to compile it so I cannot debug it (or at least I don't know how).

What is the problem?

Comment: `fgets` keeps the new-lin character at the end of the line, which contributes to the `strlen`. You can `strtok(line, "\n")` to remove it. `strtok` is in `<string.h>`

Comment: Printing the lines that are longer than `sizeCap` would show you the problem.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`); BTW, use `g++` for C++ code and `gcc` for C code, since C and C++ are different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) reads and stores the trailing newline `\n`. This `\n` gets counted as one *element* while calculating [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen).

You need to strip off that `\n` after taking the input.

- Manual Way

  1. check the `strlen()`.
  2. check the `n-1`the byte for `\n`, replace with `\0`.
  3. calculate the *final*(actual) `strlen`.
- Using library function

**using `strchr()`**

1. You need to use [`strchr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) to find out the trailing `\n`.
2. if found, replace the `\n` to `\0` using the retuned pointer.
3. Also, you can get the new string length by subtracting the returned pointer from the original input string.

   Sample Code:

   ```
   int length = 0;
   char*nl=strchr(line,'\n'); 
   if (nl) 
   {
       *nl='\0';
       length =  nl - line;
   }
   else
       length = strlen(line);
   ```

**using `strtok()`**

1. Have a look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) of `strtok()`. After reading the input, you can *parse* the string using `\n` as delimter.
2. calculate the `strlen()` of the returned token, if it is not NULL.

Some suggestions:

1. always check the return value of `fopen()` against NULL to ensure the success.
2. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: Why is it doing it? I mean add `\n` to the end of line

Comment: @user1432980 that is how `fgets()` behave. Check the link I provided for more details.

Comment: For finding the `\n`, `strchr` is much better -and faster- than `strtok`; and no need to compute `strlen` twice.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sir, 1) for _finding_ the presence of `\n` `strchr()` is better of course, but here, we need to strip off the `\n`, i.e., we need a _string_ without the `\n`, so in that case, is not `strtok()` a better choice? 2) You are right, that was a typo. Removed the double-`strlen()` check..

Comment: No, just code `char*nl=strchr(line,'\n'); if (nl) *nl='\0';` (and you could even avoid calling `strlen` when an `\n` is so found, by using in that case `nl-line`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I understood sir. Will update my answer accordingly. Thanks for the comment. :-)

Comment: I am surprized so many people are using `strtok`. I find that function disgusting and used it only once (since 1985), then gave up using it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sir, _maybe_ the reason behind this is the ability to handle  multiple delimiter at a time. Don't really know. :-)

Comment: Your revised code would crash when no `\n` is found

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you once again sir. Somehow missed that part. Updated accordingly. :-)